# NoSQL - Migrating from a NoSQL DB to another

Tags: database, nosql

This is a general question : Do you know if there exists application(s) for moving from a NoSQL DB to another? There are a lot of methods for migrating from SQL to NoSQL but I did not found for NoSQL to another.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score -1):

There are [150 NoSQL tools](http://www.nosql-databases.org/) coming in different flavors (document, key/value, graph, column-store) and the leading vendors constantly add/change features.

A general tool that assists you to migrate from A to B wouldn't make sense. It would never be up-to-date and couldn't support you in data modeling for the target system.

But you will find assistance from NoSQL vendors. They will guide you how to extract data from lets say a MongoDB and get it into Couchbase. In reality you will not migrate 1:1 from a NoSQL solution to another as you perhaps switch for a particular reason - and that might need changes in the data modeling / indexing as well.

Comment: Here is an example from cassandra, on how to migrate from mongodb http://planetcassandra.org/mongodb-to-cassandra-migration/

Comment: I don't want a general tool! I wanted to list all different apps for migrating from a NoSQL db to another :). (Personaly I want to migrate from Neo4j to HBase)
And thank you for the link!

Comment: There is a paper that describes the process... maybe that helps: For migrating data from Neo4j as a **graph database** to HBase as a **column family** database. The following pattern should be travelled: http://www.researchgate.net/publication/260799066_Design_Patterns_to_Enable_Data_Portability_between_Clouds'_Databases